# Why java.util.Set has arbitrary methods "of"?

Tags: java, collections

As you can see [here in documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) that there are 11 methods named `of` in `Set`:

```
static <E> Set<E> of​()
static <E> Set<E> of(E e1)
static <E> Set<E> of(E e1, E e2)
//similar 8 methods like above till e10
```

Now coming to the 12th `var-args` method:

```
static <E> Set<E> of(E... elements)
```

The method in second snippet essentially does the same as those methods in the first snippet. My question is, why did Java developers included the 11 arbitrary methods(first snippet) in `Set` interface? Do we really need those methods when we have a `var-args` method?

And which method will be invoked if I pass only one argument to `of`?

`static <E> Set<E> of(E e1)` or `static <E> Set<E> of(E... elements)`.

Comment: Most likely for performance reasons - to use varargs, an array needs to be created which is passed to the method; without varargs, creating this array is avoided. Which method will be invoked if you pass only one argument: Obviously, the version that takes one argument!

Comment: [Now you may ask, what is the point of having 11 extra methods if there’s a var-args version which can work for any number of elements.

The answer to that is performance. Every var-args method call implicitly creates an array. Having the overloaded methods avoid unnecessary object creation and the garbage collection overhead thereof.](http://www.baeldung.com/java-9-collections-factory-methods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass a single argument, `static <E> Set<E> of(E e1)` will be executed, since methods with varargs have a lower priority during method overloading resolution (i.e. they are only considered by the compiler if no methods without varargs are applicable).

The 11 `of` methods were created for performance reasons. They are more efficient than the varargs method, since the varargs method requires instantiation of an array.

Comment: nitpick, only 2 of them at the moment are using a separate implementation, others still delegate to `var-args`